# Tag Docker image with the same version as in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-build

I have a Dockerfile generated by a python script in order to write a `version` label the same as `__version__`.

```
from src.mypackage import __version__

docker = """FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.9-slim

LABEL version="{}"

ENV ...

COPY ...

RUN...
""".format(__version__)

with open('Dockerfile', 'w') as writer:
    writer.write(docker)
```

During the building process, I'd like to tag the image with the same version in the label `version`. 
Like `docker build -f docker\Dockerfile -t myproject:<version> .` 
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can the same script `subprocess.run(['docker', 'build', '-t', __version__, ...])`?

Comment: I didn't think about it :D, but yes I can.. So Docker does not allow such a thing?

Comment: There's not a place to specify the image tag other than the `docker build -t` option (or the related `docker tag` command, or equivalent Docker API calls); you can't write it in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Summary

Unfortunately, there really isn't a way to tag an image version inside a `Dockerfile` if that's what you're asking, but there's a few ways to accomplish the same result with a reasonable workflow.

It may *seem* odd, as it's easy to think "a `Dockerfile` version should correspond to the version of the `image` it builds," and while this does *seem* to make sense, your image's build process defines whether it's 'pure' (eg. whether it is ***exactly*** reproducible or not) - for example, if your `Dockerfile` does anything relying on external resources that get updated (like `apt update && apt install <package>` or does `apt upgrade`) then you can easily end up with vastly different built images even when building using the *exact* same `Dockerfile` and while it's possible *your* `Dockerfile` is pure in it's output, that doesn't mean it always will be for everyone nor can `docker` really tell in advance whether it is or not.

That aside, others have build processes setup where their `Dockerfile` doesn't really ever change but builds/pulls newer/latest versions of resources possibly depending on variables with the intent of being able to create new/updated image versions *without* ever changing their `Dockerfile`.

I highly suspect these reasons are at least part of why you're expected to provide the image tag/version when running the `build` command. (I do think perhaps you should be able to specify a default *name* for the image inside the `Dockerfile` (perhaps using the final stages `AS` name?), but that's an aside.)

Note, that while you can specify a name using `AS` for the **current build stage**, I don't think that's what you want as it doesn't affect the saved/exported image name/tags:

From the `Dockerfile` documentation:

> `Optionally a name can be given to a new build stage by adding AS name to the FROM instruction. The name can be used in subsequent FROM and COPY --from=<name> instructions to refer to the image built in this stage.`

### Workarounds

Below are some common methods/workarounds to get the desired result while still being easily manageable.

#### Method Using `compose` Files

If you're using `compose`, you can specify a name and tag for a build in your `compose` file, such as:

##### `compose` definition

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  my_service:
    container_name: my_service
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: my_service_image:latest
```

#### Method Using Variables, `--build-args` and `ARG`|`ENV`

You can also use a shell script like a `build.sh` (or implement the same directly in your `python` script) to apply your tags normally with `docker -t` but using variables to set the version tag in one place such as environment variables and also pass them on using `--build-args` to be used inside your Dockerfile, like so:

(I personally do this so that even if I'm using something like `compose` that the build stage is separated and I end up with a properly named/tagged image that I can then use in a `compose` or a `pod` definition also knowing it's been properly built and tested)

##### `build.sh` Shell Script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

BUILD_IMAGE_NAME="my-image"
BUILD_IMAGE_VERSION=1.1.0
BUILD_IMAGE_UBUNTU_VERSION=22.04
BUILD_IMAGE_TAGS="-t org/${BUILD_IMAGE_NAME}:${BUILD_IMAGE_VERSION}"
BUILD_IMAGE_ARGS="--build-arg BUILD_IMAGE_NAME=${BUILD_IMAGE_NAME} --build-arg BUILD_IMAGE_VERSION=${BUILD_IMAGE_VERSION} --build-arg BUILD_IMAGE_UBUNTU_VERSION=${BUILD_IMAGE_UBUNTU_VERSION}"
BUILD_ARGS="--progress plain ${BUILD_IMAGE_TAGS} ${BUILD_IMAGE_ARGS}"

docker build ${BUILD_ARGS} - < Dockerfile
```

##### `Dockerfile` for your build image

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1-labs

# ARGs needed for FROM and their defaults
ARG BUILD_IMAGE_NAME="default-image-name"
ARG BUILD_IMAGE_UBUNTU_VERSION=22.04
FROM ubuntu:${BUILD_IMAGE_UBUNTU_VERSION} as ${BUILD_IMAGE_NAME}-build-stage

# bring the above ARGs into context
ARG BUILD_IMAGE_NAME
ARG BUILD_IMAGE_UBUNTU_VERSION

# Other ARGs and their defaults
ARG BUILD_IMAGE_VERSION=1.0.0

# Set Labels
LABEL version=${BUILD_IMAGE_VERSION}
LABEL name=${BUILD_IMAGE_NAME}
LABEL ubuntuVersion=${BUILD_IMAGE_UBUNTU_VERSION}

# ADD etc

RUN <<END
  echo "Building ${BUILD_IMAGE_NAME} v${BUILD_IMAGE_VERSION} based on Ubuntu-${BUILD_IMAGE_UBUNTU_VERSION}"
  echo " ... "
  echo "Done!"
END
```

Then you can just run `./build.sh`, which is also convenient for CI/CD processes. Of course you could also define the variables in `build.sh` in your environment instead of in the script itself allowing them to be easily passed in by CI/CD or otherwise or you could modify the script to define the variables based on command line arguments so you could run `./build.sh my-image 1.2.3 22.04`.

The `docker` command in `build.sh` will tag the resultant image with your specified name and version as you requested and also make it available inside your `Dockerfile` to be used to set `LABEL`s and other commands also as you requested with it all being set in a single place for easy management.